# How to use a custom php version on a subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, shared-hosting

In a bluehost subdomain I want to use a different php version. Default is 5.4, I want to use 5.6. According to this [link](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess-php-handlers) all I have to do is add a `.htaccess` file

```
# Use PHP5.6 as default
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpbeta .php
```

But the php is not running, so no page is showing.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned it is a subdomain. Are you using a free hosting service.

All the server options wont be available for a free hosting service.

Check which version of php is installed using,

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If the website page is blank, reason could be, errors might have been disabled by default. So enable php errors and check. 
Also, check server error log.

Comment: the `phpinfo()` is disabled, but I can see php version using `phpversion()`